# Im about to refresh the current viewed Fragment from searching an item from API

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my application I am about to refresh the current viewed fragment after searching an item from API. My search bar is coming from Fragment activity and, when the result is there, it will be viewed in the second fragment, but the problem is, **when I click search, it will reset into the 1st fragment.**

Here's my code:

```
private ViewPager mPager;
private MyPagerAdapter mAdapter;
ImageView settings_btn;
EditText search;
//EditText search;
ImageView community_icon;
ImageView loyalty_icon;
ImageView tokens_icon;
Context context;
public CustomerAccount customerAccount;
private MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

String offer = "cheese";
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

CustomListAdapterMerchant adapter;
String searchname;

ArrayList<RowItemMerchant> rowItem;
JSONObject offerlist;
int i;
JSONObject merchantList;
RowItemMerchant items;
ListView listView;


Bundle extras;
String empty;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);


    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        search.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("Key"));
    }
    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    search.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                ConstantSearch.SEARCHNAME = search.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                intent.putExtra("IPUTTEDMERCHANT", ConstantSearch.SEARCHNAME);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.d("SearchName",ConstantSearch.SEARCHNAME);
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }

    });

    search.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value
            // with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                ConstantSearch.SEARCHNAME = "";
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                intent.putExtra("IPUTTEDMERCHANT", ConstantSearch.SEARCHNAME);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.e("IME_TEST", "DEL KEY");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bd = intent.getExtras();
    if(bd != null) {
        String getName = (String) bd.get("IPUTTEDMERCHANT");
        search.setText(getName);
    }

    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if(!enabled) {
        showDialogGPS();
    }

    mAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    final TextView ref1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ref1);
    final TextView ref2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ref2);
    final TextView ref3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ref);
    final ImageView Image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    final ImageView Image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    final ImageView Image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);

    settings_btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.settings_button);
    settings_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent settings = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, SettingsPromotion.class);
            startActivity(settings);
        }
    });

    ref1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.orange));
    Image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_community_on);

    ref2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blackColor));
    Image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_loyalty_off);

    ref3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blackColor));
    Image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tokens_off);




    ref1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            setToDefault();
            ref1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(DashboardActivity.this, R.color.orange));
            Image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_community_on);
        }
    });

    loyalty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            setToDefault();
            ref2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(DashboardActivity.this, R.color.orange));
            Image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_loyalty_on);
        }
    });

    tokens.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            setToDefault();
            ref3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(DashboardActivity.this, R.color.orange));
            Image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tokens_on);
        }
    });
}
public  void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);{
        String savedText = search.getText().toString();
        savedInstanceState.putString("Key", savedText);
    }
}

private void showDialogGPS() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("Allow \"My App\" to access you location while you use tha app?");
    builder.setMessage("My App uses this to help customers find places. connect with merchants and more");
    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            startActivity(
                    new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Ignore", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

public void setToDefault()
{
    TextView ref1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ref1);
    TextView ref2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ref2);
    TextView ref3  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ref3);
    ImageView Image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    ImageView Image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    ImageView Image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);

    ref1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blackColor));
    Image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_community_off);
    ref2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blackColor));
    Image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_loyalty_off);
    ref3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blackColor));
    Image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tokens_off);
}

public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private static final int NUM_ITEMS = 3;
    private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private FragmentOne fragmentOne;
    private FragmentTwo fragmentTwo;
    private FragmentThree fragmentThree;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentTags = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
        fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();
        fragmentThree = new FragmentThree();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        if (position == 0)
        {
            return fragmentOne;
        }
        else if (position == 1)
        {
            return fragmentTwo;
        }
        else if (position == 2)
        {
            return fragmentThree;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("AuthActivity", "ViewPager invalid position");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```